# Android Record media - if the app always use the mic to record how can stop the record if other app try to use the mic

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I'm developing app that record all the time with the mic,
But when some other app (for example Google now) try to use the mic it simply can't . it says the mic is in use.

How can I stop the record if other app trying to use the mic,
There is focus listener or something like that?

Thanks!